# Select an existent Google Map Element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, google-maps, yii

In a page of my website i've got an (autogenerated by 2amigos/yii-google-map-library plugin) google map init script.

```
(function(){
function initialize(){
  var mapOptions = {"center":new google.maps.LatLng(43.8998984000,12.8599824000),"zoom":14};
  var container = document.getElementById('gmap0-map-canvas');
  container.style.width = '512px';
  container.style.height = '512px';
  var gmap0 = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
  };
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
})();
```

with jquery i've a function for add a marker ( triggered on a certain event )

```
 function(e) { 
         var lat = e.params.data.coords.lat;
         var lng = e.params.data.coords.lng;
         var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: coords,
               title: 'Test',
               map: gmap0
         });
         gmap0.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

}
```

The scripts are launched in this order so the var gmap0 is declared first. but if go to execute the code it returns me this error:

> ReferenceError: gmap0 is not defined

what can i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must declare your var outside the initialize function   so the var is visible to the other function

```
<script>
var gmap0 ;
 (function(){
 function initialize(){
  ....
  gmap0 = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
  .....
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: great, i didn't think about this